# Can I read the mail and download the attachments using that imaplibrary in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Can I read the mail and download the attachments using that imaplibrary in VB.Net

Comment: **that** imaplibrary? Which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using something with proper queuing and logging if you intend this for a business app.

here is an existing question along these lines, with good responses.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544895/imap-library-for-net